# How to I get three cells pr row in a UICollectionView. (Works on simulator, but not on phone)

Tags: ios, swift

I am playing around with `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to learn, but I cant seem to find out how to get three cells per row.

When running my app on the simulator I get three cells pr row (What i want), but when running the code on my phone i get only two cells with alot of spacing between the columns. (See screenshot)

Here is the code that sets up the Cells :

```
private func setupCollectionViewItemSize()
{
    if(colletionViewFlowLayout == nil)
    {
        let numberOfItemsForRow: CGFloat = 3
        let lineSpaceing: CGFloat = 3
        let interItemSpacing:CGFloat = 3

        let mySize = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width - 6) / numberOfItemsForRow
        print("Item size rectangle is \(mySize) and the total frame width is \(self.collectionView.frame.width)")

        colletionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        colletionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: mySize, height: mySize)
        colletionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        colletionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        colletionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = lineSpaceing
        colletionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = interItemSpacing            
        collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(colletionViewFlowLayout, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you might provide.  I have tried to substract more the 6 points, but it doesnt matter. It seems to work on the simulator but not on my phone**s**

The output from the print statement is : Item size rectangle is 135.0 and the total frame width is 414.0

Meaning the calculated size pr cell should be 135x135 and the total frame width of the collectionview should be 414 on my iphone 11 pro

Screenshot from simulator and phone: 
[image: Screenshots from simulator and actuall phone]

[image]

Comment: If you are willing to be iOS 13 only this is very easy with Compositional Layout.

Comment: I think i figuried it out.   I was calling the setupCollectionViewItemSize method from viewWillLayoutSubViews.  When i call the method from ViewDidAppear it worked.

Comment: Yes, that’s fine if you won’t rotate or change width later. Actually viewDidLayout is the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the itemSize, you simply need to conform your `ViewController` to  **`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`** `protocol` and implement the below methods,

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    enum Constants {
        static let interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 3.0
        static let lineSpacing: CGFloat = 3.0
        static let itemsPerRow = 3
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (collectionView.bounds.width - (Constants.interItemSpacing * (CGFloat(Constants.itemsPerRow) - 1))) / CGFloat(Constants.itemsPerRow)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return Constants.interItemSpacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return Constants.lineSpacing
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've also created an `enum Constants` to define the constant values required in the methods.

Also, specify the `scrollDirection` in the `storyboard` itself instead of doing it programatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make your collection view conform to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and use this method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    guard let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else  { return CGSize.zero}
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1

    let width = collectionView.bounds.width / 3 - layout.minimumInteritemSpacing

    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    return size
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried to swap mine code with yours, but it didnt change anything.

Comment: If i substract another 11 points from the itemSize it works when the iphone is vertical. But where does the 11 points come from ? :)

Comment: @BluE_MoOn are you using storyboard?

Comment: @ Luis Ramirez  Yes, I am :) . I think my mistake was to call my function from ViewWillLayoutSubview and not ViewDidAppear . Not when it is the correct time to call this function

Comment: @BluE_MoOn just updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.